# Windows 7 64-bit Random Slowdown when developing C/C++ Applications (any IDE or Compiler), Installing or Searching for WIndows Updates, etc

Tags: windows-7, performance, updates, service-pack

I originally posted this on stack overflow and realised that it was OT for there. I hope it is not an OT here as well.

My problem first started when I was using an Open Source C/C++ Library called OpenCV. Here is my original problem description http://answers.opencv.org/question/3996/cannot-do-anything-with-opencv-anymore-on-windows/

However, before sleeping last night I was doing some digging and realised that I cannot even search/install windows updates because it causes the same damage. My machine just slowly dies and become unresponsive. My Googling suggests that Windows 7 64-bt SP1 installation caused this trouble before and a hotfix from MS will do the job for me. However, I downloaded the hotfix from Microsoft Site and it is complaining that a "Disk" is missing which is a part of the fix???? Also, my machine is Lenovo Ideapad V470 and I went to Lenovo Support Site to find this hotfix. However, installing that patch didn't solve my problem either.

I know that under these circumstances, the obvious answer is, "System Restore", but I deem it unnecessary (at least not yet) to just do it without consulting experts on this site. I have raised an issue on MS Support Site, but just like their product they are unresponsive. I don't know what to do now except wait for you guys to give me a good answer. Stackoverflow , before transferring me to you, said that it could be the hardware drivers as Windows' driver quality is below standard all the time!!! Any clues?

KR,

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed to solve the problem, there was a security update in Windows 7 64-bit that caused major corruption on my PC's .dll files.

I restored everything to my laptop's original build settings (i.e. restored the windows from the hidden partition). So, everything as it was OTS (Off-The-Shelf) and now I am successfully making C/C++ developments without breaking anything!!

Comment: @Ramhound       For future reference, please don't downvote an answer and say,"I have to downvote this answer"...because you have done it already...I am more than obliged to clarify my answer further if you simply ask....thanks...

Comment: At least I gave a reason for my downvote. Since you provided what you did ( i.e. you used the factory restoration image ) I removed my downvote.  If you mentioned which update broke your installation I would upvote your answer and question.

Comment: @Ramhound       Good question! What broke my installation? My best discovery that I think broke my previous build was the Service Pack 1...I don't know how but it did....because my google research suggest that it broke a lot of PCs in a similar fashion..I don't know anything better (yet) however, I am keeping a log of important updates that are being installed as I continue with my current installation..Everytime I do an update, I will check it with visual studio 2010 and OpenCV :p...If I manage to get something better, I will let you know...for real...